# Securing Password on Java Program

Tags: java, security, java-security

I have a program where the username and password is hard coded. So I want to pass that Executable JAR file to colleagues working in the same network. I want to secure the Password and don't want to reveal it to anyone. Is there a way where I can pass on the JAR File and keep my password secure without anybody coming to know about the password.

Maybe if there is a way of storing some password in a file and keeping it on a server and every time, the JAR file tries to run, it picks up the pass from the remote file?

Comment: No there is no bullet-proof way for this. Someone could always get the password at runtime from memory.

Comment: You could use some sort of a simple character replace encryption, and keep the key on the local machine.  But even that is not 100% secure.

Comment: @DavidPulse If that idea could work, could you tell me how to implement it on Java or some kind of example.

Comment: Well, you could use a hash, and just google that like `hash java` and send it over a,preferably, secure connection. Usd can choose JSON or RESTful, which I'm not familiar with, the latter. But just send a key pair and if it matches allow access. It's somethjng you could get a book on and never be unhappy you did.

Comment: @durbnpoisn is there any example for character replacement that you provide me with? and if I keep the key on local machine, how do I remotely use that key? because if I use it in another remote system, i will again require a password to be hard coded to get access to that remote machine.

Comment: http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/whatisrest.html

Comment: @DavidPulse Cool, I will try using that and see if it works. Thanks

Comment: Welcome, have a good time learning :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your headline and the content of your question are somehow contradicting. A hardcoded password ain't **secure** in the very first place.

I would recommend a different design: create some kind of service that allows access without a password; for example based on the network address of the client. That service would then be the only piece that really needs to know this password. And come the day that have to change something (like the password, or the actual software you are using) ... there will be only one thing you need to change.

Meaning: configure your JAR to trigger some RESTful service for example ... which in turn internally calls whatever application needs that username/password.

Comment: I will try using REST and see if it works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a salted hash (hashing a random number + the password). It would ask them for a password and would hash the password and salt and compare it to the stored one. This is very weak security but is at least better than comparing it to a hardcoded password.

The hash function should be cryptographically secure, like SHA256. If you're not familiar with cryptographic hashes, it takes data of any size and mangles it down to a small fixed size fingerprint (MD5 is 128 bits, SHA1 is 160 bits, SHA256 is 256 bits, etc)

Here are examples of md5:

```
md5("abc"): 900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72
md5("not secure"): 116e54e126621ed4070b2f30ebc07fec
```

So instead of storing the password "not secure" in your file, store the hash "116e54e126621ed4070b2f30ebc07fec" instead.

Comment: Neither is what he's trying to do, but it will be sufficient for his needs. I've read the white papers and know how the MD5 attacks work. If you feel so strongly about it slaks, maybe you could demonstrate to us all how insecure it is by finding the message for "b1474b76e54e34244298766f27d04106" or at the least find another message that will cause a collision. Easy enough, right Slaks? :)

Comment: @New2Programming This looks good, I think this will be better than having it hard coded. Thanks a lot :)